# jquery .on() is not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following code:

```
console.log($(".resultLike"));
$(".resultLike").on("click", function (event) {
    alert('test');
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('test1');
    value['clicked'] = 1;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'scripts/php/userProfile.php',
        data: {
            action: value
        },
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (profileData) {
            if (profileData == 'removed') {
                $(me).children('.resultInside')
                .children('.resultData')
                .children('.resultLike').html('Favourite?');
            } else if (profileData == 'notLoggedIn') {
                $(me).children('.resultInside')
                .children('.resultData')
                .children('.resultLike').html('Login to add');
            } else {
                $(me).children('.resultInside')
                .children('.resultData')
                .children('.resultLike').html('un-Favourite');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My expectations is that when you click on the div `resultLike`, then it will preform the `function()`.  However, it does nothing.  I have two `alert()` calls in there, and neither is being called.  The output of `console.log()` is as follows:

```
[
<div class=​"resultLike searchBarGameLike">​</div>​
]
```

That proves it's being put on the page.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

I think it should be mentioned that I'm actually using two .on() events. 
This is actually all my code.  The issue is around the 
`$("body").on("click", ".resultLike", function(){`
Line, it's not working.

```
$searchedGamesContainer.on(
    "click",
    ".box",
    function(event){
        if(!$displayLock){
            $displayLock = true;
            var description;
            var user_id;
            if($(this)[0].style.width == '75%'){
                var org_img = $(this).children(".resultInside").find("img").attr("src"); 
                $(this).children(".resultInside").append("<img src='"+org_img+"' id='imgId'/>");
                $(this).children(".resultInside").css('height','auto');
                $(this).css('width', '18%');
                $(this).css('height', 'auto');
                $(this).find(".resultData").fadeOut('fast');
                setTimeout(function(){$searchedGamesContainer.masonry('reload');},300);
                setTimeout(function(){$displayLock = false;},1000);
            }else{
                var me = this;
                var pos; 
                largeImage=  new Image();
                value['name']=$(me).find("p").html();
                oldImage = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
                for(var i = 0; i<$searchBarGames.length; i++){
                    if($searchBarGames[i][5] == value['name']){
                        pos = i; 
                        break
                    }
                }

                description = $searchBarGames[pos][2];
                $(me).find("img").hide();
                largeImage.src = $searchBarGames[pos][4];
                $(me).find("img").attr("src",largeImage.src);
                $(me).children(".resultInside").css('height','400px');
                $(me).css('width', '75%');

                $(me).children(".resultInside").html("\
                    <div class='resultData'>\
                        <div class='resultImg'><img src='"+ largeImage.src +"'></div>\
                        <div class='resultName'>" + value['name'] + "</div>\
                        <div class='resultDesc'>" + description +"</div>\
                        <div class='wikiLink searchBarGameWiki'><a href='http://wikipedia.org/wiki/" + value['name'] + "'>Wikipedia</a></div>\
                        <div class='resultLike searchBarGameLike'></div>\
                    </div>");
                value['clicked']=0;

                $.ajax({
                    url:'scripts/php/userProfile.php',
                    data:{action:value},
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(profileData){
                        //logic
                    }
                });     

                console.log($(".resultLike"));

                $("body").on("click", ".resultLike", function(){
                        alert('test');
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        alert('test1');
                        value['clicked']=1;
                        $.ajax({
                            url:'scripts/php/userProfile.php',
                            data:{action:value},
                            type: 'post',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success:function(profileData){
                                //logic
                            }
                        });
                    }
                );  
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: When you post code, please make sure it is readable.

Comment: I don't know how to shift-tab all that code over.  It just tabs me to a different element in the browser.

Comment: You have to do it in your code editor.

Comment: That's the odd thing, it's fine in my editor.  Using Sublime Dev build.

Comment: Your tabstops were most likely not set to 8.

Comment: What is searchedGamesContainer? Are you sure its callback is being executed?

Comment: `var $searchedGamesContainer = $('#searchedGames');`
And I'm fairly certain, as when you click the `$('#searchedGames')` the 'box' expands. It's the inner .on('click') that isn't working.

Comment: @Adola - Please create a new JSFiddle at www.jsfiddle.net with some HTML and the script. It's a bit too much hassle to try to imagine what you're trying to achieve, and the context of the Javascript

Comment: @YngveB.Nilsen http://jsfiddle.net/HQZk7/1/ Sorry for the late reply.  As you can see, this is the behaviour I"m trying to get.  The red box is the .box, and the blue one is the .resultLike.  

I want to call a function when the blue box is clicked.  it works there in JSfiddle, but not in my code.  And I dont' know why.

Comment: Actually, small update.  Seems to work on every other element but the div I'm using as a button...

Comment: I see you fixed it, but I forked your fiddle anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/yZaSA/ :) You should think about tidying up your Javascript a bit also. Take it as a learning experience :)

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$("body").on("click", ".resultLike", function(){
      // your code goes here.
});
```

Your implementation will likely not be bound if the `div.resultLike` is added dynamically

Comment: i tried your solution, and it did not work.  And if by added asynchronously, you mean it was added dynamically, then yes.

Comment: You got the arguments the wrong way round. @Adola: Try again.

Comment: Still no change.  What's the significance of $("body")?

Comment: @Adola -he's delegated the event. A sound practice when dealing with multi-element events.

Comment: So, because this isn't working, is there anyway I can use Chrome to help be find where I should start fixing this?  I mean, I'm willing to dump more sections of code, but no one wants that!

Comment: @Adola You can read more about it here - http://api.jquery.com/on/. You would often want to use a closer parent than "body", but I don't have your code, so I chose body.

Comment: I suppose I should mention this: I'm actually using two .on() functions. 

Imagine a box that when clicked, expands and inside a button you click. 

So it's actually like: 
`$container.on("click",".box",function(event){//logic $$("body").on("click", ".resultLike", function(){
      // your code goes here.
});}); `

So, does that affect anything?  
I mean, having TWO .on() things going on at once?

Comment: I suggest you update your question with that, and if possible add some of your code to a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @YngveB.Nilsen I've updated my OP.  I hope the extra information can help us squash this bug.

Answer (score 0):

This problem actually ended up being completely because of CSS.

For the div element I wanted  the alerts on, I had markup to look like a button.
However, I noticed this:

```
.resultLike:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
    z-index:1235;
}
```

I'm not 100% why, but I think this was actually changing where the button was when clicking it.  Meaning as soon as it was active, it wasn't where your mouse was.  I could be wrong, but this fixed it.